# Print views fields in a custom view page template

Tags: views, theming, entities

I am trying to create a custom view page template which will be made of custom fields, which i am trying to print. I created a view page and added all the needed fields to it.

Next, I created a views-view--my-page-name.tpl.php template, which get's recognised, however when i try to print the fields, i get the errors below:

Notice: Undefined variable: fields in include...

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in include....

Below is the full code of my custom view page template which i copied from the default view page template and modified it. Im trying to print the field with this code:

```
<?php print $fields['views_field_field_name']->content; ?>
```

I tried all variables of field name as: field_name, field_field_name, views_field_field_name, but none of them work, as they all give same error.

```
<div class="<?php print $classes; ?>">
  <?php print render($title_prefix); ?>
  <?php if ($title): ?>
    <?php print $title; ?>
  <?php endif; ?>
  <?php print render($title_suffix); ?>


  <?php if ($exposed): ?>
    <div class="view-filters">
      <?php print $exposed; ?>
    </div>
  <?php endif; ?>

  <?php print $pager; ?>

  <?php if ($header): ?>
    <div class="view-header">
      <?php print $header; ?>
    </div>
  <?php endif; ?>

  <?php if ($attachment_before): ?>
    <div class="attachment attachment-before">
      <?php print $attachment_before; ?>
    </div>
  <?php endif; ?>


<?php print $fields['views_field_field_name']->content; ?>
<?php print $fields['views_field_field_age']->content; ?>
<?php print $fields['views_field_field_phone']->content; ?>


  <?php print $pager; ?>


  <?php if ($footer): ?>
    <div class="view-footer">
      <?php print $footer; ?>
    </div>
  <?php endif; ?>

  <?php if ($attachment_after): ?>
    <div class="attachment attachment-after">
      <?php print $attachment_after; ?>
    </div>
  <?php endif; ?>

  <?php if ($more): ?>
    <?php print $more; ?>
  <?php endif; ?>  

  <?php if ($feed_icon): ?>
    <div class="feed-icon">
      <?php print $feed_icon; ?>
    </div>
  <?php endif; ?>

</div><?php /* class view */ ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using template for display, here you will do theming for overall display, the `$fields` variable is not available here.

If you want to change how fields are printed relative to each other, row style, then you should use `views-view-fields.tpl.php`, in your case the name will be like `views-view-fields--yourpagename.tpl.php`.

but if you want to theme individual fields then you have to use `views-view-field--yourfieldname.tpl.php`.

Comment: Im using the display template beacuse i only want to put a wrapper around the printed fields.

I don't want to make any changes to the fields except to put each of them in a wrapper with a different class each, separately, so i can theme them.

How could i just print the Label + Content of the fields on the display template?

Comment: Create a template file like `views-view-fields--yourpagename.tpl.php` and copy the contents from `views-view-fields.tpl.php` and add your wrapper.

Comment: But wouldn't that add the wrapper with same class to all fields? I want to add wrapper with different class around each field.

Comment: You will be having field name & label based on that you can create your wrapper.

Comment: I did as you suggested. Below is the code i have in my view-fields--mypagename.tpl.php

`<div class="col-sm-12">
 <?php foreach ($fields as $id => $field): ?>
   <?php if (!empty($field->separator)): ?>
    <?php print $field->separator; ?>
   <?php endif; ?>
  <div class="col-sm-3">
   <?php print $field->wrapper_prefix; ?>
   <?php print $field->label_html; ?>
   <?php print $field->content; ?>
   <?php print $field->wrapper_suffix; ?>
  </div>
 <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>`


But this put class="col-sm-3" wrapp around each field. How could i use different class on each field wrapp.

Comment: you can add `$field->label` to your class name.

Comment: Yes but it would add field label as a class. It is not what i need. I need to be able to add different classes to the wrapper manualy, in form of col-sm-1, col-sm-3, col-sm-5. Since i use Bootstrap framework i would like to stick to it.

Is there a way to target a individual field and not all of them? How could i add wrapper to just one of the fields, not all of them?

Comment: Then you can do it two ways. 1. Either create a template file for individual field. 2. Or, In your current fields template file instead of looping through fields, you directly print the fields by their name like `$fields['title']`

Comment: Thank you very much, that works! Im using the current fields template and printing fields directly by their name, but i had to remove `<?php foreach ($fields as $id => $field): ?>` since it was printing all of fields with same content, i hope it was supposed to be removed.

Once again, thank you so very much and best of luck!